# trying to get multimap to print out questions

Tags: c++, printing, random, multimap

The multimap contains `multimap<int,Questions*> map;`.  Im trying to get the map printing out using the following method:

```
Questions* Questions::printQuestion(int level)
{
    multimap<int, Questions*>::iterator it;
    pair<multimap<int, Questions*>::iterator,multimap<int, Questions*>::iterator> ret;

    ret = map.equal_range(level);
    if(ret.first != ret.second)
    {
    size_t sz = distance(ret.first, ret.second);
    size_t idx = rand() % sz;
    advance(ret.first, idx);
    it =ret.first;
    return (*it).second;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

But the method does nothing.  Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: have you tried putting in print statements to see what is modified and when it stops working?

Comment: where is your ``map`` variable defined ?

Comment: defined in questions.h and this code is in Questions.cpp

Comment: Do you mean that it always returns NULL, or that it doesn't do any printing?

Comment: @JohnMcG  That it doesnt do any printing.

Comment: In that case, I don't see any code that is supposed to actually print.  From what I can tell, this simply returns a pointer to a random set of questions for the provided level.  The calling function would then need to do the printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function doesn't print anything. It returns a `Questions*` that is randomly chosen from all questions with the given level. So if there are three questions with level 5, and you call `printQuestion(5)`, you will get a pointer to a random question of those three. If you want to print the question that is chosen in this function, you will have to do something like so:

```
Questions* question = (*it).second;
std::cout << question->getText() << std::endl;
```

Replace `getText()` with whatever you need to do to print the question.

If you want the client that calls the function to print the question, you'll do:

```
Questions* question = printQuestion(5);
std::cout << question->getText() << std::endl;
```

By the way, it's not very common to name classes with the plural form.  It'll be easier to read your code if you class is called `Question` instead of `Questions`.